# How can I put the desktop files on other drive, e.g. D:?

Tags: windows

I use Win7 and usually I put some files on my desktop so that I can access them easily. But I like to backup files on other driver instead of drive C. So I want to find a way that I can put those files on my desktop while they are stored on D drive. Is it possible and how to do? Thanks!

I hope to access them easily: means that they can be saw directly on desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tweak registry settings with earlier versions of Windows so that the USER directory is located on other drives:  that is no longer the case since Windows 7.

The closest you can come to doing what you want to do is placing your files on the D: drive, and dragging a shortcut onto your Desktop  (you can also create a symbolic link to your desktop directory, but that's more trouble, and there's no real advantages).

Perhaps a safer alternative is to use the vanilla Windows functionality, but use one of the online backup services like Mozy to keep the files safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the files onto your D drive and right click on each file and click "Send To" then click "Desktop(create shortcut)".